# Fail to install tcpdump package in UBI8 (Red Hat Universal Base Image)

Tags: rhel, docker

I am building a docker image based on UBI8(Red Hat Universal Base Image), Dockerfile looks like

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi-minimal

RUN microdnf install sudo zip tar bash procps openssl iptables net-tools tcpdump && microdnf update; microdnf clean all

ENTRYPOINT [ "/usr/sbin/tcpdump" ]
```

But it failed to install tcpdump package.

```
Downloading metadata...
error: No package matches 'tcpdump'

(process:57): librhsm-WARNING **: 22:03:51.398: Found 0 entitlement certificates

(process:57): librhsm-WARNING **: 22:03:51.400: Found 0 entitlement certificates

(process:57): libdnf-WARNING **: 22:03:51.400: Loading "/etc/dnf/dnf.conf": IniParser: Can't open file
```

How to fix it in order to install a tcpdump package in UBI? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

In my case I'm creating custom version of image which is based on ubi8-minimal (https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak), so I cannot change the base image.
The support-tools image is not public available - registration required.
I've ended up with manual installation:

```
curl http://mirror.centos.org/centos/8-stream/AppStream/x86_64/os/Packages/tcpdump-4.9.3-1.el8.x86_64.rpm -o tcpdump-4.9.3-1.el8.x86_64.rpm  
microdnf install shadow-utils  
microdnf install libpcap-14:1.9.1-5.el8.x86_64  
rpm -i  tcpdump-4.9.3-1.el8.x86_64.rpm
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use registry.redhat.io/rhel8/support-tools as the base image instead. It comes with tcpdump-4.9.2-6.el8 among other troubleshooting tools.

http://ftp.redhat.com/pub/redhat/containers/rhel8/support-tools/8.2-19.txt

e.g.

```
oc import-image rhel8/support-tools --from=registry.redhat.io/rhel8/support-tools --confirm
```